# If SKAction Repeat Action Count Ends

Tags: swift, count, sprite-kit, skaction

I have a ground object being repeated 23 times:

```
var moveGroundSpritesForever = SKAction.repeatAction(SKAction.sequence([moveGroundSprite]), count: 23)
```

How can I create an if statement in swift for when this count finishes to perform another action?
Thanks

Comment: Do all actions have the same duration or do you have a way of finding the longest duration? If so, run another sequence with a waitForDuration and runBlock action. Otherwise increase a counter in completionBlock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `func runAction(action: SKAction!, completion block: (() -> Void)!)`. `completion` closure will trigger when all your repeated actions are executed